# VBA, count the visible rows in a table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried the following,

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

However this always returns 1, I suspect is it because the data is within a table? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in a table, use a ListObject object:

> [ListObject object
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject)

Then count visible cells **only in a single column** of the data range:

Something like this should work:

```
Dim Mytable As ListObject

Set Mytable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

Debug.Print Mytable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

Set Mytable = Nothing
```

If your data **is not** a table object but just a range of cells then do:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```

Replace`Range("A1")` with a cell of your header row. And because this count will add also the header row itself, we must do -1 at the result of the count